# CSS menu based on unordered list with no class

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I want to know if it is possible to design a multilevel menu for below mentioned menu structure based on css only. On cssmenumaker.com one can see several examples and & menu with 2 - 3 level submenus they usually add a class like `has-submenu`.

Can we do it with any any classes to the sub menu and manage it from css only.

something like

```
.nav ul {}
.nav ul ul {}
.nav ul li{}....


<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Image Gallery</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Video Gallery</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Example on fiddle has example based on cssmenu.com also http://jsfiddle.net/zo61z9sw/

http://cssmenumaker.com

Or we have to use any sort of jquery which can handle multilevel menus also.

Comment: What I think you could do is something like this `.nav ul li:hover > ul {display:block}` so anytime you hover over a li, if it has a child `ul` it would be shown.

Comment: @wf4, i just say jqeury based menu, in actual source they dont add any css to the HTML. i think jquery is doing all the work http://www.smartmenus.org/ please advice

Comment: I don't have the source to check, but yes using javascript (jQuery) it is possible that from 1 class on the top container, the script can go down and add classes to style the menu... e.g. it could check each li in the container, give it a class "menu1". if any "menu1" class has a child li, give that a class "menu1-2" and so on...

Comment: You can do this without the `has-submenu` class; a quick (and dirty) amend to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lottszm7/

Comment: @HiddenHobbes, Thanks this working fine can you please point out the changes you made... so that it can help others also.. Please also put as Answer so that  i can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle this works because the sub menu `ul` is nested inside the `li` so:

- Set the sub menu `ul` to `display: none;` by default
- When the parent `li` is hovered set the child `ul` to `display: block;`. This is done via `li:hover > ul` where `>` will ensure only immediate children `ul` to the `li` will be effected

In this case instances of `.has-sub` aren't really needed as the same check can be done on all `li` and will only do anything if a child `ul` is found.

**CSS:**

```
/*CSS for menu without subclasses*/
#testmenu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 52px;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
 #testmenu ul, #testmenu li, #testmenu span, #testmenu a {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#testmenu:after, #testmenu ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#testmenu a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2edea 0%, #c0bebf 100%);
    color: #666666;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 52px;
    padding: 0 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#testmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 whitesmoke;
}
#testmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
#testmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#testmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4a5662 0%, #606f7f 100%);
}
#testmenu ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#testmenu ul > li ul {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#testmenu ul > li ul li a {
    background: #606f7f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #59636f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #556371;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #606f7f;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 160%;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#testmenu ul > li ul li:hover a {
    background: #4a5662;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#testmenu ul > li li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#testmenu ul > li li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#testmenu ul > li li ul li a {
    background: #606f7f;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#testmenu ul > li li ul li a:hover {
    background: #4a5662;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

I've stripped some of the vendor prefixes to shorten the code but this CSS can probably be optimised to remove/consolidate some of the styles.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/x9fmzc82/